Is c# EPPlus library thread-safe for reading multiple sheets in a same Excel file?
I'm working on some toy project using EPPlus and C#.
While reading other articles, I know using EPPlus library for editing an Excel file on multiple threads is not thread-safe.
However, I only want to use EPPlus for reading.
Is the EPPlus library still not thread-safe for reading multiple sheets in the same Excel file from multiple threads?
Thanks in advance.

Check the documentation for the library. If it does not mention thread safety, assume it is non-thread safe. In theory, pure read operations should always be thread safe, but there is no easy way to know if a library method might do some writing or not. You could try opening the file as read only, but shared. That might allow multiple independent readers to be created.

Like @JonasH said, read ops are typically thread safe.  However, Epplus likes to use a lot of singleton pattern implementations.  So if common things are being created/updated during the reading of sheets from different threads, it is possible to get collisions depending on their implementations (e.g. they are not using static properties as backers).  Probably why the authors do not promote it as thread-safe.  What about reading the file and cloning the Stream in memory?  Increases memory pressure but not so bad if the file is not huge.
